# Current tab from storyboard

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitabbarcontroller

If I create a Tab Bar Application project template with storybard and put this in my AppDelegate.m:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
NSLog(@"Root: %@", self.window.rootViewController);
NSLog(@"Current ViewController: %@", /*self.window.rootViewController.selectedIndexOrSomething?*/  );
return YES;
}
```

It says: Root: <UITabBarController: 0x6b20360>

So I guess the TabBarController is already added as a subView of the window property as I have not touched the AppDelegate in any other way than NSLog.

How to log the *current* tab/ViewController?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to do this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    NSLog(@"Root: %@", self.window.rootViewController);
    NSLog(@"Current ViewController: %@", ((UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController).selectedViewController );
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but this is not giving me any results in log just (null)

Comment: Have you added the viewcontrollers?  You can check with NSLog(@"TabBar ViewControllers: %@", ((UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController).viewControllers );